# How to include non-db data in results returned by prisma?

Tags: prisma

I'm using prisma with sql server so I can get a list of users just fine using

```
const res = await prisma.user.findMany()
```

I'd like to know how to prepend some text to one of the columns, similar to what the raw sql as below would do:

```
select 'abc' + field1, field2 from users
```

Comment: Hi, I work with the Prisma team and we're gearing to release the SQL Server Connector in GA. Did you find a suitable workaround to this issue? Please feel free to get back to us about this or suggest any other requirements you think we should prioritize [here](https://prisma103696.typeform.com/to/VhNTd0TM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use Prisma's [raw query mechanism](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) or add this data in your application logic after you fetch the data.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, I was hoping prisma had a builtin way to do this without resorting to those options as neither are ideal.

Comment: I would suggest opening a feature request [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=) so that we can look into this

Comment: Although not strictly prisma, if using graphql as per this link it may be an option:  https://v1.prisma.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-common-resolver-patterns-ct08/#scenario:-add-a-custom/computed-field-to-a-prisma-model-via-the-application-schema-prisma-bindings